# Cambio de servidor error, mensaje SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes amigos,

es un gusto saludarlos, me gustaría que por favor me ayudaran con la siguiente pregunta. hice un cambio de servidor cpanel y ahora no me funciona algunos procesos, la credenciales están bien, pero genera el siguiente mensaje  `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Line: 37 ( `$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$dbport;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";`) Ya estuve revisando, pero no logro salir del error.

```
    
class Connection
{
    protected $dbh;
    private static $_instance;
    private $logger;

    /**
     * Connection constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logger = new Logger(self::class);
      $this->logger->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(Constants::LOGS_PATH . 'querys.log', 20,Logger::DEBUG));
        $dotenv = new Dotenv();
        $dotenv->load(__DIR__ . '/../../environment.env');
        try {
          $host = $_ENV["DB_HOST"];
          $dbname = $_ENV["DB_NAME"];
          $dbport = $_ENV["DB_PORT"];
          $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$dbport;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
          $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $_ENV["DB_USER"], $_ENV["DB_PASS"]);
          $this->dbh->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
          $this->logger->info("Connection SuccesFully DB", array("pdo" => $this->dbh));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
    Get an instance of the Database
    @return Instance
    */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->dbh;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿No usas contraseña?

Comment: Revisa lo que tienes en `$_ENV["DB_PASS"]` y verifica que sea la contraseña correcta para la base de datos.